# Cannot set keyboard using raspi-config

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, raspi-config, locale

When I plug a USB keyboard into my Raspbian (buster) pi 3B+, and I try to use the pipe key `|` I get a tilda `~` instead.  This is consistent across a bunch of keyboards that work well in other computers.

I see in `raspi-config` under "Localisation Options" I can "Change Keyboard Layout".  There's a long list, so I pick something generic like "Logitech" and then it asks me to configure the "Keyboard layout".  Here it presents a long list of options in Cyrillic and Greek and non-English languages but nothing that looks appropriate for USA/English, or even anything that looks Western-European.  Even under something plausibly simple like "Frans" I see a huge list of choices, again with lots of Cyrillic and Greek that all look wrong, and make me worried my keyboard will become completely useless if I select one.

To be as clear as I can about version I'm running:

```
$ uname -a
Linux leopi6 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: No "English (US)" option after you pick the keyboard? (Sorry, edited)

Comment: Nope.  No English (US) option in sight.  I've got Albanies or Yslandies or испанска — латиноамериканска or черногорска or lots in between.

Comment: Wow, what are you running? If you picked Generic-101 key there will be no Eglish layouts to pick from when you scroll?

Comment: Raspbian buster - details in main question.  Also, FWIW there's no "Generic-101" in the keyboard list.  There's "Generies 101-sleutel PC" which google tells me is Afrikaans for "Generic 101 key PC".

Comment: I've seen that `raspi-config` mess (to be fair, I don't think it is `raspi-config` that created it) using a fresh Raspbian lite buster install.  It's totally broken, but you can do it manually.  Gimme a minute to see if I can remember how.

Comment: Turns out "испанска — латиноамериканска" is Bulgarian for "Spanish - Latin American", so I bet the "English (US)" option was there, but translated into some non-Western alphabet for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here it presents a long list of options in Cyrillic and Greek and non-English languages but nothing that looks appropriate for USA/English, or even anything that looks Western-European. Even under something plausibly simple like "Frans" I see a huge list of choices, again with lots of Cyrillic and Greek that all look wrong

I have seen this screen and it is clearly not working properly.

Edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and set:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="symbolic"
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

The second one is what's most important; it was probably (`gb`). Then reboot.  This should be permanent and affect both console and GUI mode.

See also `man 5 keyboard` for an explanation of where to find available options, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  raspi-config is great when it works, but...

Comment: This was far more straightforward for me than using raspi-config, which didn't seem to change my settings upon exit

Comment: Mine is set to US but I still get, for example, a `~` instead of `|`.  Rebooted a few times already. There are other things in my /etc/default/keyboard, like `XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"`. Should I try deleting these things?

Comment: The "this is not a pipe" thing is very irritating during an install.  I've updated this to what's currently in my Pi 5 running bookworm.